# Count Script Tags

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to figure if there was some sort of way to count all  tags on my webpage so far haven't had any luck so I came to my last resort you guys!

Basically what I want is to detect all script tags getting a total where I can than

for example

```
if(scriptCount != 5) {
   //send warning that this user may be using an outside script
}
```

Comment: And do what with this info in a log file?  It's just bogus info because of all the legit add-ons that will be counted here.  Now, if you were looking for the existence of specific third party scripts (using some sort of signature identification) that you know are incompatible with the goals of your site, that would be a different thing, but a pure count is pretty worthless.

Answer (score 5):

Just get them and use `length`, of course you have to actually do this after all the script tags are available in the DOM, which means in the last script tag on the page, or inside a DOM ready handler.

```
var scriptCount = document.getElementsByTagName('script').length
```

Comment: @Kratos - This answers the OP's literal question, except that what he's trying to do with this information won't really work.  I have a couple browser add-ons (like a password manager) that add a script to every page so the site would think I'm doing something I shouldn't when I'm not.

Comment: @jfriend00 - That depends on what the OP is trying to do, if it's just to check if the user is using only the originally included scripts on the page, no browser add-ons or other external stuff, it should work just fine.

Comment: I'm simply checking to see if the user has extra scripts loading within my site without my awareness there won't be any warning messages or anything to be exact it'll simply log it.

Answer (score 1):

> send warning that this user may be using an outside script

You shouldn't.

There are many browser addons which add script tags to a page which are visible to the page's JS code. No user will tell you that they are happy because you warned them. But you will likely lose users who think that your page behaves oddly.

If you want to prevent "cheating", then this idea won't work either.

Comment: Well, not really warning them, the warning will be send to a log page via jquery to staff.